# Как проверить к какому com-порту подключено устройство?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, com-порт

Есть два ком порта. К одному из них подключаю девайс и пытаюсь считывать с Hyper - ом. Hyper  просит ком порта, естественно, я не знаю ,наугад выставляю поочередно. Понимаю, что это неправильно. Подскажите пожалуйста, с какого порта считывать Хайпером, чтобы точно знал. Есть ли какие нибудь программы, которые показывают, к какому порту подключилось ли (или нет) какое нибудь устройство, хотя бы.

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идет о настоящих COM-портах - то это невозможно: там нет никакого единого протокола, ОС ничего не знает про подключенное устройство.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите тут: [Listing serial (COM) ports on Windows][1].  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205383/listing-serial-com-ports-on-windows

Comment: Это не то что нужно. Как я понял там проверяють, существуеть ли такой то ком порт. А мне нужно, чтобы при подключений к одному из ком - ов, программка показывало к какому порту подключился устройство.

Comment: При установке устройства драйверы устанавливали?  В диспетчере устройств Ваше есть?  Какого рода устройство?

Comment: Драйвер устанавливать не требуеться. Устройство - это подключаеться к телефонному аппарату(обычной) и через ком порт передаеть сигнал, во время звонка к этому телефону, то есть должно передать номер звонящего абонента. А я вот пытаюсь считать это сигнал, пока не получаеться вот. В диспетчере устройств вижу только ком порты.